# continuous linear operator (isomorphism) on $H^1$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

> Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\rho\in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$ . Show that the mapping $v\to\rho v$ defines a
> continuous linear operator of $H^1(\Omega)$ into itself . If $\rho>0$
> on $\overline{\Omega}$ show that this operator is an isomorphism of
> $H^1(\Omega)$ onto itself .

In other words , it is enough to show $$||\rho v||_{H^1}\leq C||v||_{H^1}$$ for some $C>0$ . We know by standard definitions of norm $$||\rho v||^2_{H^1(\Omega)}=\int_\Omega|\rho v|^2+\int_\Omega|\nabla(\rho v)|^2=||\rho v||_2^2+||\nabla(\rho v)||_2^2$$ Now since $\rho\in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$ , one has $||\rho v||_2^2\leq||\rho||_\infty^2||v||^2_2$ . Now if we somehow able to show that $$\int_\Omega|\nabla(\rho v)|^2\leq||\rho||^2_\infty||\nabla v||_2^2$$ then we are done . But the product rule is not applicable here since we don't have that $v\in H^1(\Omega)\color{blue}{\cap L^\infty(\Omega)}$ . I suspect that the boundedness of $\Omega$ has to do something here (Poincaré 's inequality won't help since that works only in $H_0^1(\Omega)$) . But how will that help I can't understand .

Also some help in the second part is appreciated . Regards .

Comment: Hints: You can prove the inequality for $v$ in a dense subset of $H^1$ and then use an extension argument. For the second part, note that the inverse operator is the map $u\mapsto \frac1{\rho}u$; and since $\rho>0$ we have $\frac1{\rho}\in C^1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just write
$$
\|v\nabla \rho\|_2  \leq \|v\|_2 \|\nabla \rho\|_\infty
\\
\|\rho\nabla v\|_2 \leq \|\rho\|_\infty \|\nabla v\|_2.
$$
Is it sufficient for you to finish the question?